# Salt bridge in galvanic cell

Tags: electrochemistry

When we make a galvanic cell using zinc rod (in zinc sulphate solution) and copper rod (in copper sulphate solution), there is a flow of sulphate ions from the copper compartment to the zinc compartment through the salt bridge. Once the sulphate ions reach the zinc compartment, what happens to them?

Comment: Nothing. They are no different from those sulphate ions which were there from the beginning.

Answer (score -1):

According to my opinion i think you are wrong because the sulphate ion does not enter the other compartment. This is because the function of the salt bridge is to maintain electrical neutrality by either allowing the sulphate ion to reside in it or by allowing the cations inside the salt bridge to enter the compartment so as to balance the ions.

Comment: Can you please confirm that no sulphate ions are flowing through the salt bridge. And that, the salt in the salt bridge supplies the required ions. Thanks.